# how to compile .rst in .pdf

Tags: rst-mode

I've obtained a .html from an .rst file `M-x rst compile`

```
Compile command: rst2html.py   README.rst README.html (this is the message I obtain from emacs)
```

How can I compile in .pdf?

Renato

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `xpdf` and `rst2pdf`.

Then:

```
M-x rst-compile-pdf-preview
```

Comment: and how do I install xpdf and rst2pdf on emacs?

Comment: You don't - you install them on MacOSX.

Comment: You have to install them on your os.

Comment: pip install rst2pdf ?
or something else?

Comment: You need to learn how to install packages on your system (and that is *NOT* an emacs question). You should ask such questions on a MacOSX forum.

Comment: yes you can install rst2pdf with pip

Answer (score 0):

ok, I think I've solved.

I've installed `rst2pdf` going over the error I've received. Maybe I’ve not installed the last version of PIP. I’ve toke information here: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-pip-mac

I've installed the last version of PIP and all goes well.

Comment: Please don't pose another question in an answer. If that question is implicit in the original question then it's enough to say in your answer that it's not complete because...